# How to get a string value such as R.string.value in a ViewModel

Tags: android

I've tried many ways for "getString" in the ViewModel , as I've succeeded to getString at the MainActivity.class which the code is just getString(R.string.value) like that ... but I am clueless for getString in ViewModel , I have tried many ways such as using context, Resources.getResouces().getString(R.string.value) etc , please help me and thanks in advance

```
private int API_KEY = R.string.API_KEY;


Log.d(TAG, "getData: " + context.getString(API_KEY));
```

I expect the results is the string from strings.xml that could be get from the int of R.string.API_KEY

Comment: I hope this is what you need: [How should I get Resources(R.string) in viewModel in Android (MVVM and databinding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804291/android-access-to-r-string-from-model-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **getResources**

```
Log.d(TAG, "getData: " + context.getResources().getString(API_KEY));
```

Comment: Not sure if it is able to get the context in a customized class

Answer (score 0):

1. ViewModel class should be implemented by AndroidViewModel which has application instance by default.
2. Then getString can be used by > Example: application.getString(API_KEY)